# WP8 Pin App Elementes to the Tile menu

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to pin elements from an app to the Tiles page ? as in, the user can create a list in my app, and i would like to allow the user to pin elements from that list to the main tile page, is that possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I don't know any method names that i can make use of :/ that is the point of this thread to point me to some methods/method that can do this, i can take it from there if i have the method name :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating secondary tiles, you need to use the [`ShellTile.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile.create%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method.

Sample code:

```
string page = "/MainPage.xaml?id=" + itemId;

StandardTileData tileInfo = new StandardTileData
{
    BackgroundImage = new Uri("ApplicationTile.png", UriKind.Relative),
    Title = "Your tile title"
};
ShellTile.Create(new Uri(page, UriKind.Relative), tileInfo);
```

That will create a Tile with the specified item id.

Then, to get the item id when the user launches the app, check the `NavigationContext.QueryString` property.

Here is a tutorial: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-secondary-shell-tiles